# All Permutations of Picking Marbles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This is my first time using this site, so sorry if I do anything incorrect. I am asking this here because I couldn't find any relevant answers to my question here or elsewhere on the web. If anyone knows a webpage that has a detailed overview of this process, I would appreciate it if you could link me to it. Anyways, on to the question.

I am trying to find a general equation to determine how many permutations *p* exist for a set of marbles **M** if you select *m* at a time. For instance, for a set **M** comprising of 1 blue marble, 1 green marble, and 2 red marbles, each of which is indistinguishable aside from color, there are 12 distinct permutations *p* if you take the marbles $m = 3$ at a time. I am wondering if there is an equation that gives you *p* for any set **M** and any selection *m*. I know that the number of permutations of **M** with length\size *L* is $\frac{L!}{1!1!2!}$ if $m = L$, but what if $m \lt L$?

I have found some equations on my own that work, but only for certain sets **M**. One equation I have found is:
$$p = \sum_{i=0}^k C_i^m \cdot P_{m-i}^{n-1}$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$p = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{m}{i} \cdot \binom{n-1}{m-i} \cdot (m-i)$$
with *n* being the number of colors that exist in set **M** and *k* being the largest amount of marbles per color in **M**.
However, this only works if all the marbles are different colors except for one color.

I was also able to develop another equation for **M** of type {0,1,2,2,3,3} (with the different numbers representing colors), where there are 2 colors with 2 marbles a-piece and all the other colors have only one marble:
$$p = P_m^n + 2 \cdot C_2^m \cdot P_{m-2}^{n-1} + C_2^m \cdot C_2^{m-2} \cdot P_{m-4}^{n-2}$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$p = m \cdot \binom{n}{m} + 2 \cdot \binom{m}{2} \cdot \binom{n-1}{m-2} \cdot (m-2) + \binom{m}{2} \cdot \binom{m-2}{2} \cdot \binom{n-2}{m-4} \cdot (m-4)$$

Unfortunately that's about as far as I was able to get. I couldn't find any solid unifying equation much past that. If anyone has any ideas or knows the full equation, please share. I would be very grateful to be enlightened about this. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238906/how-many-distinct-n-letter-words-can-be-formed-from-a-set-of-k-letters-where-s?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I remember a few times writing out the fully generalized formula... it is *very* messy.  In most cases it is easier to work with the exact numbers and not use the generalized formula.  I'll see if I can find it before closing this as a duplicate of something else

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for the link. I think the answer to that post should suffice to answer my question. However, if you do find the generalized formula, I would love to see it, as messy as it may be. I am trying to find it because the specific case I'm trying to apply it to has 96 'letters', 6 of which are unique, that I need to permute into varying length 'words'. So I was thinking that a general formula would be easier than a specific case formula.

Comment: I may have been thinking of a post of mine like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279714/combination-with-finite-replacements/3279740#3279740) where I discuss the fully generalized formula for the question of combinations rather than permutations (*i.e. order of the letters does not matter, only the quantity of each used*).  The fully generalized formula for permutations will likely be just as monstrous as that one.

Comment: @JMoravitz Do you know if the answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125834/a-general-formula-for-n-distinguishable-arrangements-of-length-ell-of-a-seq/129125) post is the generalized formula for permutations?

Comment: Yes, that would work, though admittedly it is not much different than brute forcing a count by having broken into cases.

Comment: Well I just found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37211/permutations-with-identical-objects) answer on MO that I think is the best equation for it so far. It's nice and clean too.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I already saw that post and it's a bit too complicated for my purposes, but thanks for the help! :)